# Trigger com valor null

Tags: sql, sql-server

Boa noite galera, preciso que verifique se as colunas endereço e telefone estão nulas, caso esteja retorne uma mensagem de erro, caso contrário efetive a operação.
meu codigo está assim:

```
CREATE TRIGGER VERIFICA
ON cliente
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
BEGIN
DECLARE
@NOME VARCHAR(50),
@TELEFONE VARCHAR(12),
@ENDERECO VARCHAR (100)

SELECT @NOME = NOME FROM inserted
SELECT @TELEFONE = TELEFONE FROM inserted
SELECT @ENDERECO = ENDERECO FROM inserted

IF @telefone is not null and @endereco is not null
begin
    RAISERROR ('Campos nulos', 11,1);
end
ELSE
    INSERT INTO cliente (nome, telefone, endereco) VALUES (@NOME, @TELEFONE, @ENDERECO);
END
```

Comment: Isso não poderia ser feito diretamente na aplicação, evitando assim utilizar procedimento de gatilho (_trigger_) para algo tão simples?

Comment: Realmente é mais fácil tratar os nulos na própria aplicação do que no SQL, a não ser que tenha um motivo muito forte para o fazer!

Comment: Sim, seria muito mais interessante fazer isso no client service porem é apenas uma questão de universidade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem uma pequena correção na lógica e na sintaxe segundo a MSDN.

```
CREATE TRIGGER VERIFICA
ON CLIENTE
FOR INSERT
AS

DECLARE
   @NOME VARCHAR(50),
   @TELEFONE VARCHAR(12),
   @ENDERECO VARCHAR (100)

SELECT @NOME = (Select Nome from inserted)
SELECT @TELEFONE = (Select Telefone from inserted)
SELECT @ENDERECO = (select Endereco FROM inserted)

IF (@nome is null or @telefone is null or @endereco is null)
begin
    RAISERROR ('Campos nulos', 11,1);
end
ELSE
begin
    INSERT INTO cliente (nome, telefone, endereco) VALUES (@NOME, @TELEFONE, @ENDERECO);
END
```

Para gerar o meu cenário criei ilustei com a tabela cliente:

```
create table cliente 
(  
   nome varchar, 
   telefone varchar, 
   endereco varchar, 
   id int identity(1,1) primary key
)
```

E os casos de testes:

```
INSERT INTO cliente (nome, telefone, endereco) VALUES (null,null,null);
INSERT INTO cliente (nome, telefone, endereco) VALUES (null,'b','c');
INSERT INTO cliente (nome, telefone, endereco) VALUES ('a','b',null);
INSERT INTO cliente (nome, telefone, endereco) VALUES ('a',null,'c');
```

Com saída:

```
Msg 50000, Level 11, State 1, Procedure VERIFICA, Line 17 
[Batch Start Line 28]

Campos nulos
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER VERIFICA
ON cliente
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    IF Exists(
        Select inserted.campoSChave
        From inserted
        Where telefone is null Or endereco is null
    )
    Begin
        RAISERROR ('Campos nulos', 11,1);
        Rollback;
    End
END
```

Note que alterei o tipo de Trigger de **Instead Of** para **AFTER**.

No **inserted.campoSChave**, pode ser um campo qualquer da tabela de origem.

Note que como alternativa pode criar um Contrain no desenho da tabela em que pode colocar a seguinte sintaxe:

```
Not (Telefone Is Null Or Endereco Is Null)
```